# Using the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I just read about the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule and I tried to do an example but couldn't really do it.

I am trying to calculate $\chi_{(5,4,3,2,1)}^{(7,4,3,1)}$, i.e., the character associated to the Specht Module  $S^{(7,4,3,1)}$ in the conjugacy class of $Sn$ given by the partition $(5,4,3,2,1)$

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?